# picklist values on a custom object in alphabetic order

Tags: picklist

How do arrange the existing picklist values on a custom object in alphabetic order.

I have about 50 picklist values (LOV) and was wondering how can I make them appear in alphabetic order to all users.

Answer (score 4):

Click the "Reorder" button that appears by the "Picklist Values" when you click on the picklist field in the "Setup" UI. A checkbox for then appears that offers:

> Sort values alphabetically, not in the order entered. Values will be
>   displayed alphabetically everywhere.

so check that and "Save".